# Regular expression in Groovy. Catch fragment of a String

Tags: regex, groovy

Given the following input:

```
BGM+220+105961-44+9'
DTM+137:20140121:102'
NAD+BY+0048003479::91'
NAD+SE+0000805406::91'
NAD+DP+0048003479::91'
CUX+2:USD+9'
PIA+1+M1PL05883LOT+":BP::92'
PIA+1+927700077001:VP::91'
PRI+AAA:9:::1:PCE'
SCC+1'
QTY+21:10000:PCE'
DTM+2:11022014:102'
PIA+1+M1PL05883LOT+":BP::92'
PIA+1+927700077001:VP::91'
PRI+AAA:9:::1:PCE'
SCC+1'
QTY+21:20000:PCE'
DTM+2:04022014:102'
UNS+S'
UNT++1'
UNZ+1+10596144'
```

The goal is to capture from the first line:

```
BGM+220+105961-44+9'
```

the value between "-" and "end of the digit". In the above example, it would be "44".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
text.tokenize( '\n' )  // split it based on newlines
    .head()            // grab the first one
    .find( /-\d+/ )    // find '-44'
    .substring( 1 )    // remove the '-'
```

Actually, you don't need to split it, so just:

```
text.find( /-\d+/ )?.substring( 1 )
```

does the same thing (as it's the first line you're interested in)

#### Edit after comment:

To get both the numbers surrounding the `-`, you could do:

```
def (pre,post) = text.find( /\d+-\d+/ )?.tokenize( '-' )
assert pre  == '105961'
assert post == '44'
```

Comment: Could you tell me please how to get value which is before "-" char? This value is 105961. Thanks